# Time complexity of sat

Tags: algorithm, sat

How the complexity of a SAT  measured? for N variables, e.g., (A∧B)∨(A∧B), then the formula's maximum size is unbounded.Rather than how many variables it takes?

Comment: When measuring the complexity, N is not the number of variables, but rather the size of the input. Perhaps that misunderstanding is at the root of your problem?

Comment: You can always convert a formula to its equivalent [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form). So the "complexity of the formula" is also bound by the amount of variables. It is a good measure. Also, how would you informally measure the "complexity of the formula"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of variables is an appropriate measure of the complexity of the problem.  Each of the N variables can take a true or false value, so there are 2<sup>N</sup> possible inputs.  The SAT solver simply has to check whether it can find any combination of values for the inputs such that the equation (expression) produces 'true'.

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: I'm not sure what else (more) there is to be said.  Which of the three sentences is hard to understand?